# A "sample' reference not showing up a table... but shows up in standard paragraph

Tags: sample, asciidoctor

Here is my code.  It does not seem to be a malformed table entry.  The ASCIIDOCTOR-PDF 'build' produces no error and does create a PDF file.  It all works... but the table SAMPLE text is blank.

```
[cols="50,20,30", options="header"]
|===
| Result  | Key | Description 
| [.sample]#:#           | : | "Thanks for using Coast Line"
| [.sample]#;#           | ; | Modern "COAST LINE"
| [.sample]#?#           | ? | Nose Logo FULL DETAIL - Inverse
| [.sample]#_#           | _ | Boxcar details
| [.sample]#+#           | + | Built stencil
| [.sample]#/#           | / | DF Logo
| [.sample]#<#           | < | Slightly older "COAST LINE"
| [.sample]#=#           | = | Nose Logo 
| [.sample]#>#           | > | Node Logo Inverse
| [.sample]#0#           | @ | Nose Logo FULL DETAIL

|===
```

So none of the samples will show up in the table. The rightmost table entries show up as expected.

But the following in another part of the document works fine (so I know YAML is good)

```
=== Uppercase

[.sample]#ATLANTIC#
```

Since I don't get any errors, so I'm not sure how to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your sample markup, adding only a title (to make it a valid document) and a leading paragraph (to guarantee that the PDF has visible content):

```
= Document

Lorem ipsum...

[cols="50,20,30", options="header"]
|===
| Result  | Key | Description 
| [.sample]#:#           | : | "Thanks for using Coast Line"
| [.sample]#;#           | ; | Modern "COAST LINE"
| [.sample]#?#           | ? | Nose Logo FULL DETAIL - Inverse
| [.sample]#_#           | _ | Boxcar details
| [.sample]#+#           | + | Built stencil
| [.sample]#/#           | / | DF Logo
| [.sample]#<#           | < | Slightly older "COAST LINE"
| [.sample]#=#           | = | Nose Logo 
| [.sample]#>#           | > | Node Logo Inverse
| [.sample]#0#           | @ | Nose Logo FULL DETAIL

|===
```

With asciidoctor-pdf 1.6.2, the PDF generated with no errors and looks correct:

[image: Screenshot of generated PDF]

Bsed on the information that you have provided, I don't see a problem.

You are using the custom role `sample` in your markup. I'd suggest investigating your theme so see if that role is causing the rendering issue that you are encountering.

You mentioned `YAML` but there is no YAMY here, just Asciidoc markup.